# Why when mocking a private method using Powermock is calling the real method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I mock a method using a line like this in the `@Before` test method:

```
PowerMockito.when(mockedObject, method(MockedClass.class, "methodIWantToMock")).
            withArguments(Matchers.anyString()).thenReturn("AnyExpectedResult");
```

I tried this as well:

```
Whitebox.invokeMethod(mockedObject, "methodIWantToMock", "AnyExpectedResult");
```

I mock it because I don't want to execute it, but when those lines are executed, the real method is called, and I want to avoid that.
I don't know why it is happening and how to avoid it.
I couldn't find any question like this one in the site and internet. 
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized that to do that I need to add the class I want to mock inside the annotation `@PrepareForTest`.